# using the datastore to access blobstore values (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

all i am trying to do is figure out how serve a blob, by using the blobreferenceproperty stored in the datastore.

```
class data(webapp2.RequestHandler): 
def get(self):
    a = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM UserPhoto")
    blob = a[0].blob_key()

    self.redirect('/Serve/%s' % blob())

class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
def get(self, photo_key):
    if not blobstore.get(photo_key):
        self.error(404)
    else:
        self.send_blob(photo_key)
```

and the error i get is

```
TypeError: 'BlobInfo' object is not callable
INFO     2012-07-22 16:28:42,342 dev_appserver.py:2884] "GET /data HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

and now im completely lost.

im fairly sure im not far away, because my code is only slightly modified from the working version of the tutorial, but ive tried everything i can think of and i would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `blob()` to `blob` in the redirect line.

Comment: HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2012-07-22 22:28:34,312 datastore_stub_index.py:261] Updating C:\Documents and Settings\ladds\My Documents\udacity\whycantisigh\index.yaml
INFO     2012-07-22 22:28:34,342 dev_appserver.py:2884] "GET /data    HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2012-07-22 22:28:34,421 dev_appserver.py:2884] "GET /Serve/%3Cgoogle.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.BlobInfo%20object%20at%200x02586AF0%3E HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: thanks for the help, but now i get the error above and dont know where to even start trying to fix that. so any more assistance would be appreciated

Comment: What does the `blob_key()` function do? I suspect it's the culprit. The redirect is not to a key, but to a BlobInfo object. Maybe you need `blob.key()`?

Comment: thank you! i could have sworn i had tried all possible variations of blob and key.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer (mjibson mailed it - you're trying to execute the blob), but since the Python 2.7 and WSGI runtimes, you can just drop a "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()" within your handler code and inspect things from within a live running (local) instance.

Comment: It's only too bad I couldn't manage ipdb to work with it. :-( But then, I didn't dedicate much effort to that.